# MySQL Max unix timestamp to human readable format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id, uid, utimestamp
1, 1,1523438104
2, 1,1523438104
3, 1,1528182625
4, 2,1528210983
5, 2,1528210983
```

i'd like to query it returning the latest record grouped by uid but when the utimestamp column is human readable.

The end result being:

```
uid, utimestamp
1,1523438104
2,1528210983
```

My thoughts were along these lines:

```
select max(unix_timestamp(utimestamp))
from table
group by uid
```

Unfortunately this just returns the value 0 for everything, Is this possible or should I be storing the results in a view and then querying the view to get the human readable date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`from_unixtime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
select max(from_unixtime(utimestamp))
from table
group by uid
```

Comment: Well that was timed well Gordon!  Many thanks for the quick reply.  I was clearly reading all of the wrong examples but I'll now read the documentation!.  Thanks.